# Runnable Jar Opening Error (Calculator Program)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, desktop-application, executable-jar

I exported my program (code included) into a runnable JAR file on my desktop.  When I double click on it, nothing happens.  I don't think I have any code errors, but I have no idea why it won't work.  Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JCalc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3 = 0;
    int rem = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to JCalc!  The best calculator ever!");
    System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");

    num1 = myScanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");

    num2 = myScanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter an operator (+, -, %, *): ");

    String op = myScanner.next();

    if ("+".equals(op)) {
        num3 = num1 + num2;
    }

    if ("-".equals(op)) {
        num3 = num1 - num2;
    }

    if ("%".equals(op)) {
        num3 = num1 / num2;
        rem = num1 % num2;
    }

    if ("*".equals(op)) {
        num3 = num1 * num2;
    }
    System.out.print("The answer is: ");
    System.out.print(num3);

    if ("%".equals(op)) {
        System.out.print(" with a remainder of ");
        System.out.println(rem);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to add the Main Class in manifest file. Also ensure javaw.exe  is getting called on double-click.

Comment: Where and how do I do that?  I just started learning Java so I'm kinda clueless with what that means.

Comment: Your jar need to contain a folder called META-INF and inside that you need you to create a file called manifest.mf

Comment: A Command Line Interface based program is not suited to be launched by double click, since they have no visible console for input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A runnable JAR can be executed by commandline (note that you have to be in the directory where the Jar is!):

```
java -jar JCalc.jar
```

If you want to start Jars by double-clicking you have to do this:

For windows 7:

- Step 1: Start Control panel
- Step 2: Click Default Programs
- Step 3: Click Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program
- Step 4: Double click .jar
- Step 5: Browse C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
- Step 6: Click the button Open
- Step 7: Click the button OK

this is very useful for UI-applications

Comment: After I click open it doesn't change the default program.  It just closes and nothing happens.  What do I do now?

Comment: It just says the jar doesn't exist but it's right on my desktop as Calculator.jar

Comment: When I run it it says can't access it

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but how do I change the directory in command line?

Comment: `cd` and then the folder you want to redirect to

Comment: If you can ever find a way for the double click method to work for me that would be great but otherwise thanks for all the help!  Works now just had to cd desktop

Comment: well since it's _the best calculator ever!_ you should build a gui ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have created a command line application, a command line application needs a command line terminal, and most operating systems will not create one for you automatically.

If you're on Windows, you either need to open cmd.exe  and run the program from there, or create a .bat file that does:

```
java -jar thejar.jar
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure:

- You have a JRE installed directly on Windows
- The `JAR` file-type is associated with `javaw.exe` in your JRE installation. The easiest way of do this is right-clicking on the file and then selecting `"Open With"`.  If this option is not present, then **no** association exists and you can use `"Open"` to 
  define it.  `"Open With"` allows to correct an undesired association.

I assume that the `JAR` was properly generated as an executable one.  If you open it with a `zip` tool, do you see a `MANIFEST.MF` referencing your main class?